# how to modify json result before sending back to client

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

My controller returns a JsonResult like that:

```
return Json(model);
```

How can I modify the json data on the fly before it is sent back to the client. I'd like to add validation attributes to my model so I end up with something like:

```
{"Label": "Test", 
  "ValidationRules":[{"data-val-required":"This field is required.", "data-val-length-max":25, "data-val-length":"Max 25 chars." }]}
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class Product
{
  [Required]
   String Label {get; set;}
}
```

when calling Json(model)  with model being an instance of Product, I'd like to modify the json string before it is returned, so that it includes validation attributes.

Comment: You'll have to show us what you do with that JSON

Comment: see my update for more details

Comment: why not modify it before converting to json?

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a base class called ValidatableBase that has a ValidationRules property:

```
public class Product : ValidatableBase
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ValidatableBase
{
    public ValidatableBase()
    {
        this.ValidationRules = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> ValidationRules { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult GetProduct()
{
    var product = new Product();
    product.Label = "foo";
    product.ValidationRules.Add("data-val-required", "this field is required");

    return Json(product);
}
```

Inherit from this class and serialize.

Or if you're using DataAnnotations why not use the default jQuery validation and HtmlHelper methods provided by ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: thanks for helping. I use asp.net mvc but in this particular case I don't rely on a model to bind the view. I rely on a knockout viewmodel built from a json object. Creating a base class is not a bad idea. I've got many fields though, so I'll to come up with a solution for assigning a validation rule to a given field.